# DFA for words with $a$s not a multiple of 3 and at least one $c$

Tags: finite-automata

Consider this language: $$L = \{w \in \{a,c\}^* \mid 3\nmid\#a(w)\land\#c(w)>0\}$$.

Here is an automaton for the first part of language, but I do not know how to devise and attach the second part of the condition $\#c(w) > 0$. Because $C$ can come in any state.

[image]

Comment: Try to use the product construction.

Answer (score 1):

The product construction is a way of taking two DFAs for languages $L_1,L_2$, and constructing a new DFA for the language $L_1 \cup L_2$ or $L_1 \cap L_2$. In your case, $L_1$ consists of all words in which the number of $a$s is not a multiple of 3, and $L_2$ consists of all words containing at least one $c$. You have already constructed a DFA for $L_1$. Construct one for $L_2$, and use the product construction to construct one for $L_1 \cap L_2$.

Comment: should be "intersection", in places of "product"

Comment: No, I did mean product.

Comment: ok, just that it is a little more categorical than necessary for an elementary question.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need six states: Three states for the number of a's modulo 3, and for each of the three states whether a c was received or not.

Let's call these states a0, a1, a2, a0c, a1c, a2c. You obviously start in state a0. Getting a c leaves you in state a0c, a1c or a2c, or moves you from state a0, a1, a2 to a0c, a1c, a2c. Getting an a will move you from a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a0 or a0c -> a1c -> a2c -> a0c.

a1c and a2c are success states.